# MVC Owin Identity Linking multiple social accounts to a single user

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, social-networking, owin

I have MVC website that have MVC Owin Identity login.
So user can access my website using social networks.
Now I want to allow users connect more than one social network to there accounts.

e.g.
User registered using Facebook on my website.
During registration new local user was created for him with Facebook UserLogin connection.

Now on user's profile page I want to add other socials and show already connected socials.

How to do this using MVC Owin Identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution was easy.
I just check if user is logged in and attach new social to him.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Callback(string provider)
    {
        var externalLoginInfo = await _applicationSignInManager.AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (externalLoginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "SignIn");
        }

        // Check if the user with this external login provider already has a login
        if (await _applicationSignInManager.UserManager.FindAsync(externalLoginInfo.Login) != null) return RedirectToAction("Index", "Social");

        await _applicationSignInManager.UserManager.AddLoginAsync(HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity.GetUserId<long>(), externalLoginInfo.Login);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Social");
    }
```